# Can't custom anything on Docker x Wordpress Local develop for MacOS 10.13.6

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

## Problem

I built Wordpress local development env using Docker for Mac.
I can access the Wordpress admin page but can't custom anything on browser, something like background color, images..
I could change theme, and load some picture, and text.

Anyone knows how to fix it??

I tried to use Local by flywheel, MAMP, XAMMP but I couldn't..so Docker is the last bastion to me.
I really need solution.

## Version

MacOS 10.13.6
Docker 19.03.13

## My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    #container_name: "mysql57"
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass_fB3uWvTS
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_pass_Ck6uTvrQ

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    #container_name: "wordpress"
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/html:/var/www/html
      - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress_db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: user_pass_Ck6uTvrQ

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    #container_name: "phpmyadmin"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8888:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new empty folder/project.

Add `docker-compose.yml` to your project..

[image]

..with these configuration, see comment in code below...

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  wordpress:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.25.0.0/16

services:

  # here is out mysql database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
      # - ./docker/db-dumps:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wordpress

  # here is our wordpress server
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      # our persistent local data re routing
      - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/testing:delegated
      - ./plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wordpress
    environment:
      # our local dev environment
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
      DEVELOPMENT: 1
      # docker wp config settings
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT: 5f6ede1b94d25a2294e29eeba929a8c80a5ac0fb
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |

        /* Development parameters */
        define('WP_CACHE', false);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
        define('WP_DEBUG', true);

        /* Configure mail server */
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH', false);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE', '');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST', 'mailhog');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT', '1025');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD', null);
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM', 'whoever@example.com');
        define('WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME', 'Whoever');

        /* add any more custom wp-config defines here */

  # here is our mail hog server
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - wordpress
```

Make sure your docker app is up to date, and any previous docker project is down using this command.

```
docker-compose down
```

Then in your new project folder run this command to build your new wordpress site...

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now this will build a new installation with persistent folders in your project folder...

[image]

Before you access the site you need to update the `uploads.ini` folder to an actual `uploads.ini` file with this config code...

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
post_max_size = 2000M
max_execution_time = 600
```

So now you will have...

[image]

Before you you access the site again it's probably a good idea to put some basic theme files in so your theme will run when you visit the site and admin.

[image]

For [mailhog](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/) to work and receive outgoing mail from your local wordpress environment you will need to add this to your `functions.php`...

```
// add the action
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'action_wp_mail_failed', 10, 1);

// configure PHPMailer to send through SMTP
add_action('phpmailer_init', function ($phpmailer) {

    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    // host details
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = WORDPRESS_SMTP_AUTH;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = WORDPRESS_SMTP_SECURE;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $phpmailer->Host = WORDPRESS_SMTP_HOST;
    $phpmailer->Port = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PORT;
    // from details
    $phpmailer->From = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM;
    $phpmailer->FromName = WORDPRESS_SMTP_FROM_NAME;
    // login details
    $phpmailer->Username = WORDPRESS_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $phpmailer->Password = WORDPRESS_SMTP_PASSWORD;

});
```

Now these urls below will work...

- http://locolhost - your site
- [http://locolhost/admin](http://localhost/admin) - your site wp admin (once site is setup)
- http://localhost:8025 - mailhog for viewing outgoing mail from site

So every time you `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d` on this project, your environment will boot up exactly where you left off.

*I noticed you are tying to install `phpadmin` container. If you use a decent IDE you should be able to access your database via `db` and connect using the credentials in the `docker-compose.yml` mysql settings. Less heavy containers will make your local site run faster.*

As your project grows, advanced theme development, keeping every single thing consolidated in the project/folder makes managing multiple theme project easier.

Like this for example...

[image]

Comment: OHHHHH~!!! It works!! Thank you so much you made my day!!

Comment: I am so sorry for my late reply I realized that Docker is no longer available on MacOS10.13 so I updated MacOS itself to 10.15.

Comment: No worries it working good yeah? Can you give us a +1 and mark as solved please.

Comment: sure!! I'd love to do that but I couldn't find vote button..(This is my first time to post the question)

Comment: I think I put it now. I'm happy if it's working. I put the up arrow button besides your answer.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask one more thing?? There should be app folder but I can't find it. I don't understand how could the admin page appear.

Comment: @Yuki yeah man, ask all you need. I'm just answering another question atm i'll be 10 mins

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness.. I think there should be app folder which includes wp-admin/ wp-content/ folder but I can't find it. Where's it?

Comment: I wanted to customize the theme which is already established.

Comment: Ok so `docker-compose down` any current environment you may be running. Get the theme folder and contents you want run, and place this anywhere on your mac. I keep all my local projects in the `/yuki/sites` folder. When working with docker and wordpress, your local theme folder is the project! My `docker-compose.yml` config simply maps `plugins`, `uploads` and `db` into the local theme/project folder so everything is consolidated as one project. Ok, once you've found a place on your mac to run your theme (project), add my `docker-compose.yml` into the root of the theme.

Comment: Now in this folder, run `docker-compose up -d`. This will build a new site, database, plugins etc but will use the theme (project) folder code as the theme. If you have team viewer I'm happy to show you.

Comment: Everytime you `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose down`... docker builds a brand new instance of your environment. If you *don't* use persistent mapping of plugins, uploads and database (which i'm using via `docker-compose.yml`), then everytime you docker down and up, docker will just rebuild a new installation and database. My  `docker-compose.yml` config (sim-links) maps the database, plugins and uploads into the theme (project) folder so when you docker up after docking down, the site runs/rebuilds where you last left off. (so you don't have to re-go through the installation process)

Comment: mmm Okay. I asked too much here. I think I should learn more. Thank you anyway.  You are so sweet.